# Strange revert() behavior on Etherscan

Tags: solidity, etherscan, revert-opcode

I am testing my contract, which is for an auction. I've deployed it on the Rinkeby testnet. I have a payable function that calls `revert()` if the bid being placed isn't higher than the existing bid.

To test this functionality, I placed a bid that was too low. I believe the contract did execute the `revert()` because after the transaction, my balance has only decreased by the gas.

However, when I view the transaction on Etherscan, it says

> Contract execution completed.

This seems misleading. My balance has not decreased, and the ETH are still in my test account. But on Etherscan I can see an outgoing transaction for the invalid bid amount.

My only theory for this is that Etherscan doesn't know what happened because I have not uploaded my solidity source code. Does anyone else have any theories?

Thanks!

Comment: Send us the link to the transaction on etherscan, plus possibly the source (or at least the relevant part).